# Render a collection of forms using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Rails has this pretty way to render a collection using partial

```
<%= render partial: 'erb_partials/post', collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

How can I apply this in my loop of forms?

```
<%= profile_form.fields_for :item_groups, @item_groups do |item_form| %>
   <%=render partial: 'item_groups/item_group', locals: {item_form: item_form}%>
<% end %>

<%=profile_form.submit%>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can't use the `render partial: 'path', collection: @list` method.

If you unfold your first example:

```erb
<%= render partial: 'erb_partials/post', collection: @users, as: :user %>
```

You get:

```erb
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render 'erb_partials/post', user: user %>
<% end %>
```

The above is such a common action that the [`render`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) method included the `:partial` option to wrap the `render` call in an each loop. `render` doesn't include any other iteration wrapper options at this moment.